# Video in Browser: Embed YouTube and others

Tags: html, video, youtube, flash

I want to embed videos from different video sites like YouTube, Vimeo and so on...

But I have a problem:
The Skins of the players are all different
and I want a consistent video skin.
Is there any possiblity to get this work?

I can't host the videos on my server because I have to pay for the traffic
and that would make me poor =(

Comment: I noticed website, which do something similar, maybe it will be useful: http://embedr.com/playlist/-thinkorswim.
You allowed to create playlist from various videos/various sources, and they have common player for whole playlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, no. The video site content has to include the skin for each site, unless you rip the video out and self-host it.

There's a reason for this, and I doubt you'd want to see the sites all fold/go paid because of people hijacking content without attribution.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Youtube at least has a chromeless player, you can check out the API here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted

I don't know about any of the other sites, though. I'd try Googling the name of the site and "chromeless" or "api" to see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Media Element JS](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/)

It wraps your youtube and vimeo video to a HTML5 video, no need to host the video on your website. The script from the website can take youtube and vimeo videos and make convert them into HTML5 video.

One side effect of this script is that since it can convert both Youtube and vimeo videos to HTML5 then the players will be the exact same for both of them.

Hope that helps,
regards